# Laravel unique only if input exists with the same group_ID

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I currently have an account create and login page. I have rules for both pages in my model and for my register my rules are like this:

```
public static $rules = [
    'username' => 'unique:users,username',
    'group_id'=>'required',
    'password' => 'required'
]
```

So this just basically gives an error when the username already exists.

Now I want the username field only `unique` when the `group_id` inserted, already has the same username.

So basically people can have the same username if they dont have the same `group_id`

How do I do this? I cant seem to find out how to check in the rules if the username already exists under the same `group_id`. [The laravel validation documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation) isn't saying anything about this.

Comment: Maybe you can do something with this: `'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'`
"In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 would be included in the unique check."

Comment: @hebron But this is in the model, and I want to basically only rows with an group_id of whatever the `Input::get('group_id')` is. I cant just use that in the model though?

Comment: The documentation does have a chapter about: [Conditionally Adding Rules](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules), but I have never played around with it.

Comment: @hebron Yeah but I cant seem to find the solution to my problem though.

Comment: Maybe something in a model creating event and kick back a custom error message and return false (cancels the creation).

Comment: @hebron I'll try some stuff. I'll answer my own question if I find a solution. Thanks for the suggestion and time though

Comment: @hebron Wait so you're saying my code should be like this: `'username' => 'unique:users,username,group_id'.Input::get('group_id')` ?

Comment: an out of the box solution will be.... add unique constraint for both username and group id. then put the query in the try/catch block. if it fails, check for the error code and if it is unique constraint error, then add the error in the message bag. or.... __simply extend the validation__

Comment: @itachi Yes but how do you extend the validation in this case?

Comment: @Loko I'm not sure you can have variables in the rules definitions, but I haven't played around with it.

Answer (score 0):

it is actually simple.... just extend the validation.

let's say your array looks like this

```
$input = ['name' => 'mike', 'group' => 1];
```

write the usual rules,

```
rules = ['name' => 'required|foo', 'group' => 'required'];
```

here *foo* will be the extrended rule.

Now, extend it.

```
Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) use($input)
        {
           $count = DB::select('SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM users 
           WHERE group_id=? AND username=?',[$input['group'], $input['name']]);
           return $count[0]->c;
        });
```

that's it.

it works but i prefer to put unique constraints in database and catch the error and take action accordingly.

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't the best way of extending the validation.

Comment: yes, it isn't. the best way is to put that condition in database and catch the error.... though, you can just make the above elegant with a model.... above is just an example.

Comment: I've actually found a very good way. It's actually the one hebron posted. It's exactly what I need but Im getting an error though. 


You may also specify more conditions that will be added as "where" clauses to the query:

`'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'`

In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 would be included in the unique check.

Im getting an undefined offset: 1
but when I remove the: `NULL,id`
It doesn't give me the error anymore, but it doesn't work either. But the documentation tells me I would need this. I dont know what the `NULL,ID` does

Answer (score 0):

It is in Laravel documentation.
You just have to use extended UNIQUE validation rule:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,NULL,id,account_id,1'
        ]
```

In the rule above, only rows with an account_id of 1 would be included in the unique check.

Read more:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-distinct